# Need a File Sharing and Syncing Solution

Tags: synchronization, share

**Issue:**

The designers at our company need a solution to share and sync a folder containing images and other binary files e.g. photoshop, illustrator, flash files etc..

- These files may or may not be nested
  in sub folders
- The total size of this folder is 8 GB
  and growing potentially at the rate
  of 2 GB a year.

**Current Solution (Windows Live Sync)**

Pros:

- Transparent: Live Sync works in the
  background and does not require user
  input to add files to the tree or
  commit changes.

Cons:

- Live Sync has a cap on the number of
  files within the folder being synced.
  (20,000 file limit)
- Live Sync setup is painfully slow as
  it does not seem to use the LAN
  during the initial transfer. It took
  an average 2.5 hours for one Gig of
  data.

**Ideal Solution**

We are hoping to get a recommendation on a new syncing/sharing solution that had the following features

- Synchronization takes place over the
  LAN, so it is fast.
- Synchronization is instant and
  seamless.  Simple drag and drop
  should add files to the shared
  folder.  We do not want to use
  subversion or rsync that requires
  users to commit or add files to the
  folder.
- The files are binary e.g. psd, ai,
  fla etc.
- The solution should support snapshots
  so that users can revert to an older
  version.
- The solution should be Windows 7
  compatible
- It should be a Peer to Peer (no
  server installation)

Comment: Regarding "It took an average 2.5 hours for one Gig of data." that might be a problem with your firewall. I'm using Windows Live Sync now for two computers on a 100MBps LAN, and it's transferred about 15-20GB using the P2P protocol in less then 2 hours.

Comment: Thanks Stephan, I am sure your comment will prove useful to other Live Sync users. We are currently in the process of migrating to DropBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropbox seems to fit your needs... the only point that doesn't fit your requirements is that Dropbox first syncs to the cloud and only then syncs on the LAN - they may be changing that though.

It also makes use of delta sync, so only the changes are synced and not the whole file.

Comment: This looks pretty cool. I am going to test it out.

Comment: Thanks the designers seem to like this solution. Much appreciated.

Comment: The only negative aspect is that there is no phone support. I think we may be able to live with that.

Comment: The forums have a number of active users and support staff - take a look @ forum.dropbox.com

Comment: P.S. You may want to have a look at the new .8 builds found on the forums - a lot of code re-hauling has been made since .7 and includes the ability to sync further attributes and meta-data.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp)?
It's a windows port of rsync, with an easy GUI setup.

Comment: Thanks Cory,
This solution may not work for us for the following reasons:
1. Multiple users need to access the same files and make edits to them. How does DeltaCopy deal with conflicts?
2. It requires the users to set up a batch process to sync the files. We need something that is instant. i.e. A user adds the file to the tree and it is shared with the other authorized users immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a shared drive to store all the data?  You can then have the shared drive periodically backed up.

This doesn't solve the potential problem of multiple users editing the same files, but how large of a problem is that truly going to be?

Comment: Thanks Tyler,
We struggled with the idea of mapping a network drive. We just thought that there may be a more robust solution for this out there, particularly since we may not have considered all the worst case scenarios. Lets assume simultaneous edits or conflicts was not an issue, we would still have the issue of making sure that the scheduled back up was working properly and have a way to monitor it.
Thanks for pointing me in this direction though, I will give it some deeper thought.

Answer (score 0):

[Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) might work, I believe it meets all your criteria.

It can work peer-to-peer, but if this is for more than 2 users it'll be easier to have a central location to sync to.