# Windows file Sync

Tags: windows-server-2008, synchronization

So I have a big problem at the moment. Trying to find a reliable solution for syncing 2 windows IIS servers. I need to keep the web content imaged on both. Now I have been trying to use Rsync to this point, but unfortunately file permission errors are a nightmare to manage this way.

I'm testing out dropbox, but the performance sucks. I'm more familiar with Linux stuff and I've used Rsync in the past but isn't there a native windows solution that will work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need a File Sharing and Syncing Solution](http://serverfault.com/questions/158711/need-a-file-sharing-and-syncing-solution)

Comment: Are the servers on the same LAN?  WAN?  Totally disconnected?  Since dropbox isn't cutting it - what are your performance goals?

Answer (score 1):

Using what you have you could use xcopy or robocopy (I don't remember only one or the other does it, or if both do) running in a scheduled task to copy just the differeces.

Alternately, you could set up a DFS location (or any mapped network location, really; mapped drive, etc) to host the shared files, and point IIS to the new folder location.

Comment: Robocopy with the mirror command. Or rich copy (the robocopy gui) http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithcombs/archive/2009/03/22/richcopy-bulk-file-copy-tool-released-get-it-here.aspx

DFS imo is too slow as well.

Comment: DFS may be slow (I actually haven't used it in some time), but it is automatic.  You would have to set up a scheduled task manually to do the xcopy/robocopy.  Another reason to use DFS is that it helps you scale; if you throw a new IIS server into the mix, you then have to continually add the scheduled tasks to it, or just point the new one towards the same DFS mount.

Comment: Being pedantic, DFS generally refers to the ability to create DFS namespaces. DFSR on the other hand is the service introduced with Server 2003 R2, which should be a good solution to this problem. Despite the name, DFSR doesn't require DFS to work. It's worth making the distinction between DFSR and DFS, as DFS can use either DFSR or NTFRS as the replication technology. If you're only choice is NTFRS, don't bother, however DFSR is by far the best replication solution I've used on any platform. We replicate >250Gb over slow WAN links, and it works very well. Changes replicate almost instantly.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [mirrorfolder](http://www.techsoftpl.com/backup/index.php) and had very good luck with it. Lots of options for syncing your servers with it.